# Getting all HTTP headers and traffic programmatically in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http

I need to get a frame's HTTP headers programmatically from Javascript. It doesn't need to be portable (I only need it for Chrome) and I don't mind having to add/write a specific extension.

Or, even better and more importantly, I need to have access to *all* network traffic from and to a specific site *programmatically* as it happens.

Is there a way to do this? Do I need to write my own extension to make it happen? And if so, can I write the extension in Javascript?

Writing an extension seems to be the only way to go. I could write one and use the chrome.* API like here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network If writing an extension is the way to go, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`chrome.network.devtools`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/network#method-devtools) API can only be used in a [devtools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools), which is only active when the devtools for a page has been opened.

With the [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) extension API, you can access the following information:

- Request headers (read / modify)
- Request body (read-only, [editing not (yet) implemented](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91191))
- Response headers (read / modify)
- <s>Response body</s> ([reading / editing not implemented yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058))

Requests can be [filtered](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) by URLs, request types and per tab/window.

These APIs are only available to extensions, so you have to develop a Chrome extension. Read the [Getting started tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) to get started.

Comment: Only one quick question: is there a way to run a custom non-extension function when a response is received? Basically, is there a way for me to define, in my *non-extension* code, a function that will get called by my custom extension (passing the response headers as parameters) whenever a response is received?

Comment: Actually, I realise this is a brand new question... here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049669/how-do-i-provide-an-extra-function-to-javascript-code-through-an-extension