# How do I provide an extra function to javascript code through an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write an extension that does the following:

- Defines a custom function
- Allows Javascript code *loaded* from the Internet to run such a function

The function should take as a parameter an event listener. Basically, something like:

```
newApiFunctionDefinedInExtension( function( responseHeaders ){
  console.log("Headers arrived!", responseHeaders );
} ;
```

Then using [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), my extension (which made `newApiFunctionDefinedInExtension` available in the first place) will call the listener (in the locally loaded page) every time response headers are received from the network.

I am new to Chrome extensions and cannot find a way to make that happen. It would be great to know:

- How to make a function defined in a module available to the loaded page's scope
- How to make such an EventEmitter -- is there a constructor class I can extend?

**My goal is simple: the loaded page should define a function, and that function should be called every time there is a network connection.**

Comment: The chrome.webRequest docs indicate there is an onHeadersReceived event that you can listen for. Is this not what you are asking for?

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I want a function available to the *general javascript world*

Comment: What is the __general javascript world__? it's not even a google-able phrase. Could you perhaps provide the real-world use case you are describing? Many reads of your question have not provided clarity.

Comment: Do you want `somepage.html` to call `newApiFunc`?  I'm pretty sure "isolated worlds" will prevent that (and why would `somepage` call the function in the first place?).  But you should be able to make `newApiFunc` listen for a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: @adrichman Further clarified the question.

Comment: @teepeemm THe problem is that the event is triggered by the Google API, and not vice-versa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every webRequest event receives information about a request, including the ID of the originating tab.

So, assuming that the tab exists <sup>note 1</sup>, you can use the following flow:

```
// background.js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.tabId == -1)
        return; // Not related to any tab
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {
        responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
    });
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*'], // e.g. all http(s) URLs. See match patterns docs
    // types: ['image'] // for example, defaults to **all** request types
}, ['responseHeaders']);
```

Then, in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) ([declared in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)), you take the message and pass it to the web page:

```
// contentscript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    // Assuming that all messages from the background are meant for the page:
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('my-extension-event', {
        detail: message
    }));
});
```

After doing that, your web page can just receive these events as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('my-extension-event', function(event) {
    var message = event.detail;
    if (message.responseHeaders) {
        // Do something with response headers
    }
});
```

If you want to put an abstraction on top (e.g. implementing a custom EventEmitter), then you need to [inject a script in the main execution environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), and declare your custom API over there.

<sup>note 1</sup>. For simplicity, I assumed that the tab existed. In reality, that is never true for [type](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-RequestFilter-types) "main_frame" (and "sub_frame"), because the page has not yet been rendered. If you want to get response headers for the top-level/frame documents, then you need to temporarily store the response headers in some data structure (e.g. a queue / dictionary) in the background page, and send the data to the content script whenever the script is ready.
This can be implemented by using [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) in the content script to [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background page. Then, whenever a page has loaded and the content script is ready, the background page can use `sendResponse` to deliver any queued messages.

Comment: This is one of the most fantastic answers I've ever received. Thank you so much.